# What is the problem with sessions in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Recently I've made a web application in Codeigniter which uses sessions. Now I'm working with another application using Codeigniter and sessions as well. I'm using the same name for the sessions and when I want to retrieve data from sessions it retrieves data from the other application . How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#a-note-about-concurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same name for the sessions, and presumably the same folder, it stands to reason that both applications would interface an access the same sessions.

Change the session folder path and `sess_cookie_name` to be unique per application.

Comment: Thanks, I set the different $config['sess_cookie_name'] in cofig file and now its working fine. –